# OpenNI camera calibration yaml file not found

Tags: ros, calibration, asus-xtion-pro-live, asus-xtion-pro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my first question, so forgive me for any formatting issues.
I'm trying to use the  [visp_calibration](http://wiki.ros.org/visp_camera_calibration/Tutorials/CalibrationExternalCamera) package to calibrate an Xtion pro live camera. This uses the [camera1394](http://wiki.ros.org/camera1394) package, which is giving me errors.

When I run

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

followed by

```
roslaunch calib-live-firewire.launch
```

from the tutorial, I receive a camera not found error and the warnings:

```
Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.
Camera calibration file /home/baxter/.ros/camera_info/depth_1205220468.yaml not found.
Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.
Camera calibration file /home/baxter/.ros/camera_info/rgb_1205220468.yaml not found.
```

I checked the terminal and get these same warnings when i run

```
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
```

I looked at [OpenNI: Camera calibration file not found](http://answers.ros.org/question/63122) and have run:

```
baxter@13:24:~/ros_ws/src$ ls /home/baxter/.ros/camera_info
ls: cannot access /home/baxter/.ros/camera_info: No such file or directory
baxter@13:24:~/ros_ws/src$ ls /home/baxter/.ros
latest  log  roscore-11311.pid  rosdep  rospack_cache_02456348576439424157
```

Should I have the yaml files? If so, how do I get them? I can launch the camera, but it needs to publish under the `/camera/image_raw` topic for the calibration to work, and it seems to be publishing under `/camera/rgb/image_raw` and `/camera/ir/image_raw`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/238725/openni-camera-calibration-yaml-file-not-found/) by [fleishman](https://answers.ros.org/users/27385/fleishman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2016-07-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I fixed this by following this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/openni_launch/Tutorials/IntrinsicCalibration

---

Originally posted by [fleishman](https://answers.ros.org/users/27385/fleishman/) with karma: 56 on 2016-08-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0